# Condition for max character limit and on minimum character putting condition

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to do do following match using regex.

1. The input characters should be capital letters starting from 2-10 characters.
2. If it's 2 characters then allow only those 2 characters which does not contain A,E,I,O,U either at first place or second place.

I tried:

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]{2,10}
```

It works well, but I am not too sure if this is the right and most efficient way to do regex here.

Comment: "The input characters should be capital letters starting from 2-10 characters." Does that mean that the maximum number of characters is 10? Your regex says otherwise...?

Comment: I'm a  little confused about what you want to match/not match - can you please provide some examples? Are you saying vowels are allowed, if there are more than 2 characters? Or that vowels are only allowed after the 2nd character? What has the number "25" got to do with it?

Comment: If you want to allow 2 to 10 characters, and in the case of two characters, there shouldn't be any vowel in the string, then you could use `^(?:(?![AEIOU])[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3,10})$`

Comment: @Tom and Jerry you guys are correct its 2-10 characters ..i modified. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit to Jerry, for his answer:

```
^(?:(?![AEIOU])[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3,10})$
```

Explanation:

^ = "start of string", and $ = "end of string". This is useful for preventing false matches (e.g. a 10-character match from an 11 character input, or "MR" matching in "AMRXYZ").

(?![AEIOU]) is a **negative look-ahead** for the characters A,E,I,O and U - i.e. the regex will not match if the text contains a vowel. This is only applied to the first half of the conditional "OR" (|) regex, so vowels are still allowed in longer matches.

The rest is fairly obvious, based on what you've already demonstrated an understanding about regex in your question above.

Comment: `"This is useful for preventing false matches"` - only if you use the incorrect function (`find` instead of `matches`). If you were to use `matches`, putting `^` and `$` respectively at the start and the end would not change what the regex matches at all.